# Rails MySQL auto generated column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am working on RoR 3.x with MySQL as backend.

Is there any way to modify the existing id (autogenerated with migration) in a way that can generate particular user defined pattern.

For e.g : **"Products Table"** should have values in "**id**" field like "P01", "P02" and so on, where P can be specified by the user, and 01,02 are autogenerated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered creating an additional one or two columns for the character / count then update them yourself, and leave the id alone?  Or is there another requirement that prevents that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'regular' IDs (1, 2, 3, ..., n) in this case aren't generated by rails but by MySQL (using `AUTO_INCREMENT`).  So, if you want to go with auto-generated, auto-incrementing IDs, I would suggest not messing with this.  What you could do, and what I would suggest, is creating an additional column and then populating that using a callback on your model.

Example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :user_supplied_prefix

  after_create :generate_user_supplied_id

  private
  def generate_user_supplied_id
    update_attribute(:user_supplied_id, "#{self.user_supplied_prefix}#{self.id}")
  end
end
```

The downside of this approach is that `Product.find(user_supplied_id)` won't work.  Fortunately, `Product.find_by_user_supplied_id(user_supplied_id)` will.